# Entity Framework, разделение на несколько контекстов

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть следующая ситуация.
Есть в проекте большое количество сущностей (21 шт.)
Как правильно с точки зрения архитектуры и вообще правильности нужко с ними работать?
Создать один контекст для все 21? Или же попробовать как-то логически поделить сущности на группы и для каждой сделать свой контекст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что при удачном разбиении бизнес модели на несколько контекстов можно получить преимущество по читабельности и поддерживаемости кода, можно так же столкнуться с непредвиденными трудностями при реализации таких простых вещей как:

1. Создание базы данных используя code first подход. Только один контекст сможет создавать новую базу данных, а следовательно таблиц для других контекстов в этой базе не будет.
2. Управление связями между объектами. Два связанных класса нельзя поместить в разные контексты. А следовательно, в бизнес модели должны быть не связанные группы классов, чтобы их можно было разбить на контексты.

**Добавлено**

В этом блоге подробно расписано что надо сделать, чтобы EF 6 мог нормально работать в таком сценарии: [Data Points - EF6 Code First Migrations for Multiple Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо большое, я еще сегодня столкнулся со странным явлением, которое вы описали в П.2.

Есть 2 репозитория: CarMakeRepo, CarModelRepo,
В каждом из них создается свой экземпляр контекста (от только 1 со всеми DbSet).

При добавлении через первый репозиторий данных, я не могу через 2 добавить связанные данные.

Comment: Более детально на скринах, вот здесь [ссылочка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxs17Nthz35gMm96ci1FVkR2S1k)